# How do script a file rename functions to remove random character suffix

Tags: scripting, rename

I have a bunch of files that had random characters added to the filename. I want to batch rename them original filename less the added characters all within the same directory.

Example:

**From:** `foobar.txt_fdnf` `Bubble.txt_terj` `apple.txt_fspd`

**To:** `foobar.txt` `Bubble.txt` `apple.txt`

Comment: Do your files follow the same pattern `.txt_somerandomtext` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rename` command with regex for batch rename.

In debian based distros, this package is called 'rename'; in arch based distros it is called `perl-rename`.

(This regex assumes that all the files follow this pattern: .txt_randomtext)

```
rename -n 's/\.txt_.+/.txt/' *.txt*
```

`-n` option lets you check the changes before they are applied. If you are sure that this is the way you want to rename these files, remove `-n` option and run the command again.

Answer (score 0):

In `zsh`:

```
autoload -Uz zmv
zmv -n '(*.txt)_[[:lower:]](#c4)' '$1'
```

(remove the `-n` for dry-run if happy)

Would rename the files whose name ends in `.txt` followed by 4 lowercase letters (replace `[[:lower:]]` with `[a-z]` to restrict to the 26 letters of the English alphabet without diacritics).

`zmv` will check for overlaps before starting any renaming.